# Filter works but throws error anyway

Tags: angularjs

I'm filtering a list based on the user that is logged in. It shows the exact results but in console I still get an error:

```
Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}
```

Angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter: {fields: {user: user.current}}">
 <!-- do something -->
</div>
```

Declaration of `user.current`

```
    $scope.user.current = fhauth.getCurrentUser().userId;
```

Each `object` in `question array` has an array of fields;

```
fields[
   { 
    'questionId': 1,
    'user' : 'person1'
   }
],
fields[
   { 
    'questionId': 2,
    'user' : 'person2'
   }
]
```

### Edit screenshot array:

[image]

Comment: data structure shown is invalid but appears to be object and filters are for arrays. Show actual sample of real data structure. Also show what `getCurrentUser()` does

Comment: Something looks *really* hinky about that data structure. Why are you trying to make each field an array containing a single object? Is "fields" actually an array, or is it an object with a really bizarre index?  What does the rest of `questions` look like?

Comment: @DanielBeck Updated the OP with screenshot. Looks like it's an object, any idea how I can filter on that?

Comment: By refactoring that data structure into something less bizarre, to be honest.  `questions = { 1 : {user: 'foo', otherfield: 'bar'}, 2: {user: 'baz'}, 3: {user: 'bat', etc: 'xyz'} }` leaps out as a possibility.  (Use arrays when you want to iterate through whole lists, objects when you want to find individual elements. Include IDs as object keys where they're useful, not buried inside sub-objects as just another field. Avoid unnecessary single-element arrays.)

Comment: The arrays come from a server, I can't really change anything about that

Comment: Which part is coming from the server? The whole `questions` array?  The individual 'fields' single-element arrays? Each `field` as a single object?   Because as written, `questions[]` isn't even a valid data structure -- it parses out to `[undefined, undefined, ...]`, because it's trying to reuse the same `fields` object with an object-based key each time -- so either your server is returning broken JSON or there's a lot more going on on the clientside than you've shown here.

Comment: Yes, the whole questions array is coming from server. Server returns `res.send(data)` unless I need to change it to `res.json(data)`?

Comment: I'm beginning to realize that the data structure you posted in the question doesn't at all match the data structure in your screenshot (which is still overcomplicated, though at least not unparseable).    The answer to the question probably boils down to "you've confused arrays with objects" somewhere, but based on the info given I wouldn't begin to know where that might be.

Comment: The json I posted in my post was only to show the structure in a simple way.